# How can I pass map data with props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I just wan't store and pass current props.url to the videomodal. so I can show the same active video on the video modal. I can't use usestate in the map. how can I pass it? or is there a any other solution?

Videos.tsx ( `props.url` must be in the `<VideoModal videoURL={here} />` )

```js
 <div className="video__container">
            <div className="video__item">
              {VIDEO_LIST.map((props: any) => (
                <div key={props.id}>
                  {props.id === currentItem && (
                    <>
                      <ReactPlayer
                        url={props.url}
                        playing={true}
                        loop={true}
                        volume={0}
                        muted={true}
                        height="100%"
                        width="100%"
                        controls={true}
                        config={{
                          file: {
                            attributes: {
                              disablepictureinpicture: "true",
                              controlsList:
                                "disablepictureinpicture nodownload noplaybackrate",
                            },
                          },
                        }}
                      />
                    </>
                  )}
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
 <div className="play__video">
         
          {isModalOpen && (
            <VideoModal
              handleCloseModal={closeModal}
              videoURL={HERE I NEED TO PASS THE URL}
            />
          )}
        </div>
```

VideoModal.tsx

```js
  <div className="body">
                    <div className="player-wrapper">
                        <ReactPlayer
                            className="react-player fixed-bottom"
                            url={videoURL}
                            width="100%"
                            height="100%"
                            playing={true}
                            controls={true}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: When do you want the videomodal to show the same video? Is there an event occuring so that the modal opens with the same video?

Please be more specific so we can help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could rewrite that in this way:

```
const currentVideo = useMemo(() => VIDEO_LIST.find(v => v.id === currentId ),[currentItem, VIDEO_LIST])

return ( <div className="video__container">
            <div className="video__item">
                  {currentVideo && (
                      <ReactPlayer
                        url={currentVideo.url}
                        playing={true}
                        loop={true}
                        volume={0}
                        muted={true}
                        height="100%"
                        width="100%"
                        controls={true}
                        config={{
                          file: {
                            attributes: {
                              disablepictureinpicture: "true",
                              controlsList:
                                "disablepictureinpicture nodownload noplaybackrate",
                            },
                          },
                        }}
                      />
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="play__video">
            { isModalOpen && 
              currentVideo && (
              <VideoModal
                handleCloseModal={closeModal}
                videoURL={currentVideo.url}
            />
          )}
          </div>)
    }
```

Since you need to render just one video element at time, I think you don't need a map, it's clearer to select the video element before the return statement, so you can pass the data to any other Component that needs them.